# How to add Go to Endnote to Quick Access Toolbar QAT - Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

When adding an endnote, after I type in the endnote, I want to return to add text where I earlier added the endnote.

To do this, in the endnote, I right-click, then take the option *Go to Endnote*: ["Go to Endnote" option in right-click menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQKv5.jpg).

How can I add this to my Quick Access toolbar?

I am familiar with adding items to the Quick Access toolbar, but cannot see which option I need to add.

Answer (score 1):

I have found what to do - which is easy.

Either (1) go to Word Options, then select the Quick Access Toolbar, or (2) On the Quick Access Toolbar, take the right-most option "Customize Quick Access Toolbar", then "More Commands...".

In the drop down "Choose command from:", choose "All Commands". Scroll down to "Go To Endnote". Select this, click on the Add button to add it to your QAT. The click on OK, to save the change.

[image: "Customize Quick Access Toolbar" image]

Comment: I use a Mac and had the same problem. I had found that option... but it doesn't apply the changes in my computer when I save them. I suppose it is a problem of Endnote, because it works well with any other option...